# Am I allowed to use GitLab Community Edition for commercial projects?

Tags: git, open-source, licensing, gitlab

I've been just handed the access to a VPS at work, and I thought of installing GitLab CE on it for better teamwork organisation.

Does the GitLab CE license allow me to do so?

Comment: Yes, but remember that you will have to worry about maintenance. Should something go wrong you will have to solve it by yourself

Comment: Given that the licensing of software significantly (and regularly) impacts programming, I say this is definitely on-topic for SO.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Please don't recommend other sites if you don't understand their scope, or even their name - it leads to a bad user experience when they go to a site on a recommendation from someone and it ends up being very quickly down voted, closed, and deleted. Programmers was rebranded to Software Engineering last month, and questions about the usage of specific software tools has always been off-topic.

Comment: @ThomasOwens My information might be out of date, but that hasn't been my experience. I had asked a successful question about software licensing there, and it was considered on topic. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Re-reading the comments above, I realize there's a miscommunication. KennyEvitt: product recommendations are off-topic on most SE sites, but questions about software licenses aren't, so it would depend on the question and its phrasing (e.g. whether the MIT license allows commercial use, vs. whether GitLab CE allows commercial use).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yup, it is under the MIT license. There is nothing preventing you from using it for commercial projects. The other editions simply add more features and support.

Comment: Hmm, first time I have had an answer that has been both downvoted _and_ accepted. If the downvoter would like to point out where my answer is incorrect, I will gladly edit it.